# Elasticsearch Filter by day of week

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following document structure:

```
{
    "@version" : "1",
    "@timestamp" : "2015-05-25T13:31:43.848Z",
    "type" : "myevent",
    "value": 1
}
```

Is it possible to query all documents that occured on a Sunday?

Comment: Unless you do this with a script where you take out the day of the week. The alternative is to index the day of the itself and query that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to query it with a [`script` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-filter.html) like this:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/your_index/_search -d'
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "doc['@timestamp'].date.dayOfWeek == 7"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Note that you need to make sure dynamic scripting is enabled by adding this to your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration

```
script.disable_dynamic: false
```

Answer (score 2):

Or, if you don't want to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/blog/running-groovy-scripts-without-dynamic-scripting) because of [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/9655) use a script file:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script_file": "my_date_script",
          "params": {
            "some_day": 7
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

where `my_date_script.groovy` should be placed under `/config/scripts` and its content should look like this:

```
def day = doc['@timestamp'].date.dayOfWeek; day == some_day
```

Or, as I mentioned in my comment, for faster queries (since scripts are not particularly fast) index the day of the week in the index and directly query that.